# Rewrite rule works in URLRewrite test window but not in my web.config

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule that runs perfectly:

```
<rule name="Zona-Articulo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="?zona={R:1}&amp;id={R:3}" />
</rule>
```

Sample URL:

```
www.domain.com/eshop/product-name-complete/1234
```

URL Rewrite:

```
www.domain.com/?zona=eshop&id=1234
```

So I need to convert from this pattern:

```
www.domain.com/eshop-product-1234
```

to this url:

```
www.domain.com/?zona=eshop&idpr=product-1234
```

I checked some helps and theoretically need to use this:

```
<rule name="tienda" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^eshop-([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="?zona=eshop&amp;idpr={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

In the URLRewrite test window it runs just fine, but in my `web.config` it doesn't rewrite.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you still need to handle the old inbound url format as well as the new one (if so can you provide an example)?

Comment: old url (that run correct for "Zona-Articulo" rule):
www.domain.com/eshop/produc-name-full/1234